# Has WordPress ditched BuddyPress?

Tags: wordpress

They removed BuddyPress category from their showcase, lead developer Andy Peatling is not there, and there are some sad articles on BuddyPress but nothing specific.

Do you know what the status is?

Answer (score 1):

[BuddyPress.org](http://buddypress.org/) is up, viable, and appears fresh. Version 1.2.6 was released just last month.

So, I'd say no, Automattic hasn't ditched BuddyPress.